# Render labels and data with loop inside vue-chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

How can I render data with loop

> (for; v-for) inside: { *labels*: [] } and datasets: [{ data:[] }]

in chart using (Vue-Chart.js)

```
data: {
                    labels: [

                        ***HERE***

                    ],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Assets",
                        backgroundColor: ["#4285F6"],
                        data: [

                            ***HERE***

                        ],                 
                    }],
                },
```

So far, my (render) data is (an array, inside it - few objects - and inside every objects all my data needs):

```
LABELS: 
this.array[0] ? this.array[0].asset.name : '',
this.array[0] ? this.array[1].asset.name : '',
this.array[0] ? this.array[2].asset.name : '',

DATASETS:
this.array[0] ? this.array[0].amount : '',
this.array[0] ? this.array[1].amount : '',
this.array[0] ? this.array[2].amount : '',
```

Comment: What does your data looks like?

Comment: Pal, I've edit my comment and add it there.

Comment: Why don't you create a new array, put data inside it with a loop and then use it in vue chart config?

Comment: in your loop, you check for `this.array[0]` condition everytime?

Comment: I don't have access to the data(API), so I have to use it in that way :\
Yes, because if not - it returns me undefined.

Comment: you could use `Array.prototype.map()` to seperatly generate the labels array and the dataset array. read documation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your chart config, create a new array and then use it:

```
var labelsArray = [];
var amountArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
    labelsArray.push(this.array[i] ? this.array[i].asset.name : '');
    amountArray.push(this.array[i] ? this.array[i].amount : '');
}
```

Vue chart config will go like:

```
data: {
    labels: labelsArray ,
    datasets: [{
        label: "Assets",
        backgroundColor: ["#4285F6"],
        data: amountArray,                 
    }],
},
```

Comment: This one helped me out a lot as well!